# How to reloading Video in html5

Tags: javascript, video, streaming, webrtc, peer

I making Streaming video with webRTC.

I want to reload video without stopping on HTML5.Src file is my filesystem.it's appending chunk while video playing.

Please tell me ‎(´・ω・｀)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the loop parameter to your video tag?